# Url_rewrite and php: same structure different url requests

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite urls with the same structure to different variables? For example:

```
domain.com/category/subdirectory/
```

and

```
domain.com/category/location/
```

So in that case I can catch $category and $subcategory in the first example and $category and $location in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .htaccess file to your home directory and have your rewrite rule there.
Example: .htaccess that rewrite every url to your index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

in index.php you will have to route based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but ended up writing an if on the php file to change the variable content if subcategory = to a possible location (from an array).